# How can I apply babel config ahead of an electron app's main.js, when using Spectron?

Tags: babeljs, spectron

I'm using jest to run a test script that starts an Electron application using Spectron. What is the correct way to load my babel configuration? Normally I start the app like this: `npx electron -r @babel/register .` (npm start in package.json)

My test script using Spectron tries to initialize it like this:

```js
import { Application } from 'spectron';
const app = new Application({
  path: 'node_modules/electron/dist/electron',
  args: ["-r @babel/register", "src/main.js"],
  chromeDriverArgs: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--headless'],
  chromeDriverLogPath: 'chromeDriver.log'
})
```

But `main.js` crashes with a SyntaxError on the first import statement. Clearly `-r @babel/register` is not loading.

If I construct a command from that same `path` and `args` manually at the terminal:

`node_modules/electron/dist/electron -r @babel/register src/main.js`

the application launches just fine. But looking at the chromeDriver log, I see that this command is probably not identical to what is actually called. From the log:

```
"chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "spectron-path=node_modules/electron/dist/electron", "spectron-arg0=-r @babel/register", "spectron-arg1=src/main.js", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--headless" ]
```

My hacky workaround right now is to make a `specmain.js` script with the following:

```js
"use strict";
require("@babel/register");
require("./main")
```

And then my test script successfully launches the app, now using:

```js
const app = new Application({
  path: 'node_modules/electron/dist/electron',
  args: ["src/specmain.js"],
  chromeDriverArgs: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--headless'],
  chromeDriverLogPath: 'chromeDriver.log'
})
```

What is a good approach for requiring `@babel/register` ahead of `main.js` in the context of Spectron?